# How to run a function on a separate thread in Julia?

Tags: julia

I want to run a function on a separate core.
I wrote a script that runs it asynchronously in parallel two times.

```
const results = Channel()


function my_function()
    delay = rand() * 5
    @info "Task with $delay s"
    @info "Thread $(Threads.threadid())"
    sleep(delay)
    put!(results, delay)
end


errormonitor(@async my_function())
errormonitor(@async my_function())


@info "returned $(take!(results))"
@info "returned $(take!(results))"
```

But both times in the same thread.

```
[ Info: Task with 2.9497522378270298 s
[ Info: Task with 4.956428193185428 s
[ Info: Thread 1
[ Info: Thread 1
[ Info: returned 2.9497522378270298
[ Info: returned 4.956428193185428
```

How can I run `my_function` on different threads?

Comment: It's a cliche thing to say, but have you read [the docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/)? Async, threading, and multiprocessing are, in a sense, orthogonal. Or have you just forgot to start Julia with `--threads`?

Comment: you correctly noticed that it is difficult for me to understand these things. I ran with both the --threads 2 flag and the -p 2 flag. the answer was the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`@async`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/parallel/#Base.@async) tasks run on the thread that scheduled them (thread 1 in your example).
To spawn a task on a thread, use [`Threads.@spawn`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/multi-threading/#Base.Threads.@spawn) (and make sure to start Julia with more than one thread):

```
$ cat main.jl 
const results = Channel()

function my_function()
    delay = rand() * 5
    @info "Task with $delay s running on thread $(Threads.threadid())"
    sleep(delay)
    put!(results, delay)
end

Threads.@spawn my_function()
Threads.@spawn my_function()

@info "returned $(take!(results))"
@info "returned $(take!(results))"

$ julia --threads=auto main.jl
[ Info: Task with 0.3894362661856865 s running on thread 2
[ Info: Task with 1.4960360211694967 s running on thread 4
[ Info: returned 0.3894362661856865
[ Info: returned 1.4960360211694967
```